# Understanding XQuery evaluation of a nested expression

Tags: xml, xquery

I don't understand how to evaluate this expression.
How will it evaluate to a number greater than 1, because the exists expression will always return 1 or 0?

```
for $a in distinct-values(doc("C:/BaseX/test/test1.xml")//author)

return
count(doc("C:/BaseX/test/test1.xml")//book
[exists(index-of(author, "Abiteboul"))]
)
```

text1.xml contains 5 books as the parent elements and authors as child elements.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that XQuery is not a procedural programming language, but a declarative one and you're still lacking knowledge of very basic language features like predicates, I'd recommend to work through some tutorial to get a grasp of the nature of the language.

Your query means "count all books where there `exists` an `index-of` author elements with the value `Abiteboul`", or resolving the semantics even further "count all books, which have an author of the name `Abiteboul`".

A semantically more reasonable code formatting would be to keep the brackets for the predicate in the lines above/below, and *indent* the predicate's contents.

```
for $author in distinct-values(doc("C:/BaseX/test/test1.xml")//author)
return
  count(doc("C:/BaseX/test/test1.xml")//book[
    exists(index-of(author, "Abiteboul"))
  ])
```

Anyway, the query seems a little bit complicated. Following query performs is equivalent, but  much more concise:

```
for $author in distinct-values(doc("C:/BaseX/test/test1.xml")//author)
return
  count(doc("C:/BaseX/test/test1.xml")//book[author = "Abiteboul"])
```